# Why is x3::raw necessary here?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-spirit-x3

The following code produces a large compiler error along the lines of `static assertion failed: Size of the passed attribute is less than expected.`:

```
constexpr x3::rule<struct Variable, ast::Variable> variable = "Variable";
const auto variable_def = +x3::alpha >> +x3::alnum;
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(variable);
```

where `ast::Variable` is defined as `struct Variable { std::string name_; }`.

However when surrounded by `x3::raw[]` it compiles fine:

```
const auto variable_def = x3::raw[+x3::alpha >> +x3::alnum];
```

I would expect for `+x3::alpha >> +x3::alnum` to collapse into a single `std::string` according to the [compound attribute rule](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/quick_reference/compound_attribute_rules.html):

```
a: vector<A>, b: vector<A> --> (a >> b): vector<A>
```

especially since `const auto variable_def = +x3::alpha;` also compiles successfully.

Why is `x3::raw[]` necessary for `+x3::alpha >> +x3::alnum`?

Comment: I guess your code has `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Variable, name_)` which makes `Variable` behave like a single element tuple, see https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/408 and https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/issues/463